# Prevent concurrent execution of stored procedure with ADO.NET in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, ado.net, transaction-isolation

I want to prevent two users from executing the same stored procedure concurrently. If two ASP.NET requests come in to execute that stored procedure, then those should execute in serial manner one after another.

SQL Server database and execution is handled by ado.net.

Will any of below methods help to achieve this? What is the most suitable method? Is there any other ways to achieve the same?

1. Execute the stored procedure with ado.net transaction by setting isolation level to Serializable
2. Use `sp_getapplock` inside stored procedure and release at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Execute the stored procedure with ADP.NET transaction by setting
> isolation level to Serializable

Yes you can you can use the Serializable isolation level with your ADP.NET transaction. It is the highest isolation level and it relies on pessimistic concurrency control & guarantees consistency by assuming that two transactions may try to update the same data and uses **locks** to ensure that they do not. **One transaction must wait for the other to complete and they can deadlock.**

> Use sp_getapplock inside stored procedure and release at the end

Yes you can use SQL Server application locks `sp_getapplock`. You will have to release the lock with `sp_releaseapplock`

Another option is to use [Global Temporary Tables](http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-prevent-a-stored-procedure-from-being-executed-twice-at-the-same-time/).

Comment: Thanks for the link @william . I just found this line in first para of that link "However you need permissions for the account under which the stored proc is executed" .
Does it means that permission required to execute a SP without sp_getapplock might not sufficient for a SP with sp_getapplock ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend utilizing a queuing system in the middle tier of your architecture, between ASP.NET and your database. That way requests recieved and processed in order. You can then configure the system to only process one request at a time,

Comment: Yes that is a good design pattern. but in my case i need to show sp execution result back to the user in real time. Thanks

Comment: You're not going to get any more real time by connecting straight to sql - it's still a network connection that has to make a hop

Comment: sound is look like good but not for "scalable web app". different instance run and every instance has own threads.